# Validate ABN (Australian Business Number)

Tags: c#, validation

I need some modern C# code to check an Australian Business Number (ABN) is valid.

The requirements loosely are

- ABN has been user entered
- Spaces at any point to make the number readable are allowed
- If any other characters besides digits and spaces are included - validation should fail even if there is a legal sequence of digits included
- This check is a precursor to calling the [ABN search webservice](http://abr.business.gov.au/Webservices.aspx) which will save calls with obviously bad input

Exact rules to validate the number are specified at [abr.business.gov.au](https://abr.business.gov.au/HelpAbnFormat.aspx) which are omitted here for the sake of brevity and clarity. The rules will not change over time.

Comment: Please don't link to external site unless the link is there to support content you have already put in your question. If the Australian government changes the link then the question dies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is based on [Nick Harris's](http://www.nickharris.net/index.php/2010/01/07/abn-validation-in-c/) sample but cleaned up to use modern C# idioms

```
/// <summary>
/// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781377
/// 1. Subtract 1 from the first (left) digit to give a new eleven digit number         
/// 2. Multiply each of the digits in this new number by its weighting factor         
/// 3. Sum the resulting 11 products         
/// 4. Divide the total by 89, noting the remainder         
/// 5. If the remainder is zero the number is valid          
/// </summary>
public bool IsValidAbn(string abn)
{
    abn = abn?.Replace(" ", ""); // strip spaces

    int[] weight = { 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };
    int weightedSum = 0;

    //0. ABN must be 11 digits long
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(abn) || !Regex.IsMatch(abn, @"^\d{11}$"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Rules: 1,2,3                                  
    for (int i = 0; i < weight.Length; i++)
    {
        weightedSum += (int.Parse(abn[i].ToString()) - (i == 0 ? 1 : 0)) * weight[i];
    }

    //Rules: 4,5                 
    return weightedSum % 89 == 0;
}
```

Bonus xUnit tests to keep your tech lead happy...

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("33 102 417 032", true)]
[InlineData("29002589460", true)]
[InlineData("33 102 417 032asdfsf", false)]
[InlineData("444", false)]
[InlineData(null, false)]
public void IsValidAbn(string abn, bool expectedValidity)
{
    var sut = GetSystemUnderTest();
    Assert.True(sut.IsValidAbn(abn) == expectedValidity);
}
```

Comment: `isValid &= weightedSum % 89 == 0;` --- what is the purpose of `&=` operator here?

Comment: Also - you either move null check before `abn.Replace(" ", "")` or remove the whole `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(abn)` entirely, as redundant.

Comment: I like it! Have amended accordingly. I kept it more forgiving of null inputs though. Consumers can alter to taste preference

Comment: a little sidenote: `abn[i] - '0'` can be used instead of `int.Parse(abn[i].ToString())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var abn = "51 824 753 556";

var weighting = new [] { 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 };

var isValid =
    abn
        .Where(x => char.IsDigit(x))
        .Select((x, n) => (x - '0') - (n == 0 ? 1 : 0))
        .Zip(weighting, (d, w) => d * w)
        .Sum() % 89 == 0;
```

`IsValid` is either `true` or `false` of the input ABN is valid or not.

Comment: Impressively terse but fails unit test input for `null` and `33 102 417 032asdfsf`

Comment: @fiat - Thank you. Your question doesn't ask to validate `null` and `33 102 417 032asdfsf`. It asks us to validate an ABN (an 11 digit number). The fact that I'm filtering for digits is going beyond what the question asked for. What do you think the rules for non-ABN inputs should be?

Comment: Well in my case the ABN is user typed and this would be used in an MVC validation attribute say. The 11 digits are often represented with spaces for readability so 11 digits with any number of spaces are fine. Anything where a user has added alpha chars should outright reject. This check is a precursor to calling the gov.au ABN search webservice.

Comment: @fiat - You should add the extra details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

My JavaScript version of validating ABN and ACN

ABN:

```
function isValidABN(num) {
    const weights = new Array(10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19);
    // Convert to string and remove all white space
    num = num.toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
    // Split it to number array
    num = num.split('').map(n => parseInt(n));
    // Subtract 1 from the first (left-most) digit of the ABN to give a new 11 digit number
    num[0] = num[0] - 1;
    // Multiply each of the digits in this new number by a "weighting factor" based on its position as shown in the table below
    num = num.map((n, i) => n * weights[i]);
    // Sum the resulting 11 products
    let total = num.reduce((acc, n) => {
        return acc + n;
    }, 0);
    // Divide the sum total by 89, noting the remainder
    if(total % 89 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ACN:

```
function isValidACN(num) {
    const weights = new Array(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    // Convert to string and remove all white space
    num = num.toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
    // Split it to number array
    num = num.split('').map(n => parseInt(n));
    // Set the check digit and remove it 
    let checkDigit = num.pop();
    // Apply weighting to digits 1 to 8.
    num = num.map((n, i) => n * weights[i]);
    // Sum the products
    let total = num.reduce((acc, n) => {
        return acc + n;
    }, 0);
    // Divide by 10 to obtain remainder
    let calculatedCheckDigit = (10 - (total % 10)) % 10;
    // calculatedCheckDigit should match check digit
    if(calculatedCheckDigit === checkDigit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: My ABN validation with ABN Number masking  use it  http://www.expertsuggestion.com/2019/06/abn-number-validation-with-javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
def isValidABN(ABN = None):
    if(ABN == None):    return False

    ABN = ABN.replace(" ","")
    weight = [10,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
    weightedSum = 0

    if(len(ABN) != 11): return False
    if(ABN.isnumeric() == False): return False

    i = 0    
    for number in ABN:
        weightedSum += int(number) * weight[i]
        i += 1

    weightedSum -= 10 #This is the same as subtracting 1 from the first digit.

    result = weightedSum % 89 == 0

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

in Perl:

```
# https://abr.business.gov.au/Help/AbnFormat

sub abn_is_valid 
{
    my $num = shift;

    my @w = ( 10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 );
    my @num = split //, $num;
    $num[0]--;

    my $sum;
    $sum += $num[$_] * $w[$_] for 0 .. $#w;

    return ! ( $sum % 89 );
}


# https://asic.gov.au/for-business/registering-a-company/steps-to-register-a-company/australian-company-numbers/australian-company-number-digit-check/

sub acn_is_valid 
{
    my $num = shift;

    my @w = ( 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 );
    my @num = split //, $num;
    my $ck = pop @num;

    my $sum;
    $sum += $num[$_] * $w[$_] for 0 .. $#w;

    my $vd = ( 10 - $sum % 10 ) % 10;

    return $vd == $ck;
}
```

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

Comment: But the question was tagged for C#. You are answering a different question.

Comment: I think the title is more important and search engines lead to here without saying C#. So, yeah, this is the proper place, same question. ps: I hope I'm not the only one seeing js and python solutions as well, no use to have the same question under different language categories.

Comment: That’s not how StackOverfkow works, and doing this undermines the Q&A and voting format. If you want to answer the question for Perl, ask a new question, tag it with [tag:perl] and answer it yourself. (Assuming no one else has asked it previously.) That way, people searching for this with “Perl” in their query will get to the right place.

Comment: so it does not work properly, so what? I do not see anyone asking for python or javascript solutions neither. google leads to this thread while searching javascript and acn too, is it good enough :)